# Como formar um número para ter 10 casas decimais?

Tags: java

Tenho uma operação de soma e tenho que exibir o resultado em um número com 10 casas decimais de precisão. Alguma ideia?

Comment: O que já tentou fazer? Adicione seu código na pergunta,

Comment: Depende do que é esse número. É um valor monetário ou algo assim?

Comment: é um float resultado da divisão de 2 int.

Comment: Dividir 2 int não resulta em um tipo float. Por favor, adicione o seu código editando a pergunta, para facilitar que entendamos sua dificuldade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usamos o "f" para indicar um ponto flutuante. Antes disso, especificamos ".10" para significar "Dez números após o decimal."  [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/c9Gji1)

```
    double number = 1.23456789;
    String value = String.format("Dez números após o decimal: %1$.10f",
            number);
    System.out.println(value);
```

Exemplos usando soma de dois números:

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/C3Ats1)

```
double number = 1.11111111111111111+1.11111111111111111;
String value = String.format("Dez números após o decimal: %1$.10f",
        number);
System.out.println(value);
```

---

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/uzdP39)

```
    String result = String.format("%.10f", 10.3333333333333333 + 3.33333333333333333);
    System.out.println (result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String value = String.format("Dez casas decimais: %1$.10f",10/3d);
 System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Legal a resposta Rovann, mas seria interessante explicar um pouco seu código para que fique mais claro.

Comment: é um float normal, resultado da divisão de 2 int.